# Azure Data Factory, How get output from scala (jar job)?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory

We have a Azure Data Factory pipeline and one step is a jar job that should return output used in the next steps.
It is possible to get output from notebook with dbutils.notebook.exit(....)
I need the similar feature to retrieve output from main class of jar.
Thanks!

[Image of my pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6xAj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Actually,there is no built-in feature to execute jar job directly as i know.However, you could implement it easily with Azure Databricks Service.</strike>

Two ways in Azure Databricks workspace:

[image]

If your jar is executable jar,then just use `Set JAR` which could set main class and parameters:

[image]

Conversely,you could try to use `Notebook` to execute [dbutils.notebook.exit(....)](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#notebook-workflows) or something else.

Back to ADF, ADF has [Databricks Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook) and you can get output of it for next steps.Any concern,please let me know.

---

Updates:

There is no similar feature to [dbutils.notebook.exit(....)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook#passing-parameters-between-notebooks-and-data-factory) in Jar activity as i know.So far i just provide a workaround here: storing the parameters into specific file which resides in the (for example)blob storage inside the jar execution.Then use [LookUp activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#use-the-lookup-activity-result-in-a-subsequent-activity) after jar activity to get the params for next steps.

---

Updates at 1.21.2020

Got some updates from MSFT in the github link: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/46347

> Sending output is a feature that only notebooks support for notebook
>   workflows and not jar or python executions in databricks. This should
>   be a feature ask for databricks and only then ADF can support it.
>
> I would recommend you to submit this as a product feedback on Azure
>   Databricks feedback forum.

It seems that output from jar execution is not supported by azure databricks,ADF only supports features of azure databricks naturally. Fine...,you could push the related progress by contacting with azure databricks team. I just shared all my knowledges here.

Comment: I guess you didnt understand my question. I have added an image of my Azure Data Bricks pipeline. As you can see, I have a JAR activity, that should pass some parameter to the next step...... If i use a NOTEBOOK step, i am able to pass parameters with bdutils.notenook.exit() as I sad before. So i am wondering if there is a possibility to do that after invoking actually a job. my main class return parameters, but if i see output json of activity from pipeline, it doest pick them

Comment: @Elisabetta Sorry for the misunderstanding and i update the answer.

Comment: @Elisabetta i also created a feedback here:https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/46347  to see if we could get any official help there.

Comment: Thank you! As a workaround it's possible to save parameters from a job using globalTempView that is shared whithin a spark session. But any way it's seems stange that its possible to pass params from notebook and not from jar job.....

Comment: @Elisabetta hi,i still focus on the above feedback and get some updates, i posted it in my answer.